# Validate dynamically generated input fields as well as static fields

Tags: jquery, validation

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {

        $('.buttonaddrate').hide(); //first time hide add button
        $('<p style="float:left;"><span style="float:left;">For</span>\
                        <input type="text" id="people' + i + '" name="people[]" value="" placeholder="People" class=" one columns people" />\
                         <input type="text" id="rate' + i + '" name="rate[]" value="" style="margin-right:4px; margin-left:3px;" placeholder="Rate" class=" one columns  rate" />\
                    <span style="float:none; margin-left:8px;" class="removerate" id="removethis"><a class="button large_button delete"  id="remScnt"><span></span>rate</a></span><span class="buttonaddrate"><a class="button large_button add" id="addScnt"><span></span>rate</a></span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);

        i++;
        return false;

    });
    //remove button code
    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {

        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            $('.buttonaddrate').hide();
            i--;
        }
        //this code append add button to previous remove button
        if (i = $('#p_scents p').size() - 1) {

            $('<p style="float:left;"> <span class="buttonaddrate"><a class="button large_button add dd" id="addScnt"><span></span>rate</a></span></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);

        }

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but if you're trying to perform functions and bind events to dynamic elements, you need to use `$(body).on('#selector', function() { ... });`

Comment: @r3mus - not necessarily. only if OP is using jquery 1.7+. But more likely, OP is using an older version looking at `.live()` & `.size()` in his code.

Comment: @Krishna right -- good point.

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` to compare in `if` statement

```
if (i == $('#p_scents p').size() - 1) {
       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind a click or some other function to your selector but NOT ON DOCUMENT READY. IF you do it in `$(document).ready`, the element will not have existed by the time you are hooking up the event and therefore, will never fire.

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is a deprecated function (from 1.7+) and

removed completely from jQuery 1.9+.

You can instead use `.on()` or `.bind()` methods or

assign a function using onClick attribute